# eXist-db XQuery Sandbox: Problems in XPath expressions with doc()

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

I am using eXist-db Version: 1.4.1 (SVN Revision: 15155, Build: 20110815) and I am having problems in XQuery queries with XPath expressions when they involve names of elements or attributes, and XML data comes from the doc() function.  I tested the following queries in the XQuery SandBox.

The following query in XQuery

```
xquery version "1.0";
let $data := <users>
    <user id="1" gender="male">Jon Doe</user>
    <user id="2" gender="female">Jane Smith</user>
    <user id="3" gender="male">Some Guy</user>
    <user id="4" gender="female">Some Gal</user>
</users>
return $data//user[@gender="female"]
```

Produces the expected result.

```
<user id="2" gender="female">Jane Smith</user>
<user id="4" gender="female">Some Gal</user>
```

However, if I move the XML data to the file /db/test.xml in eXists (with this content)

```
<users>
    <user id="1" gender="male">Jon Doe</user>
    <user id="2" gender="female">Jane Smith</user>
    <user id="3" gender="male">Some Guy</user>
    <user id="4" gender="female">Some Gal</user>
</users>
```

and execute the query

```
 xquery version "1.0";
 let $data := doc("/db/test.xml")
 return $data//user[@gender="female"]
```

the result is the empty set!

The weird part is that I manage to obtain the expected result if I omit the names of elements and attributes, as in this query

```
xquery version "1.0";
let $data := doc("/db/test.xml")
return $data//*[@*="female"]
```

It even works if I use XPath axis instead of abbreviations

```
xquery version "1.0";
let $data := doc("/db/test.xml")
return $data/descendant-or-self::node()/child::*[attribute::*="female"]
```

I manage also to list all the texts in the XML file with

```
xquery version "1.0";
let $data := doc("/db/test.xml")
return $data//text()
```

But it simply doesn't work if I use names of elements or attributes in XPath expressions

This does look like a bug but I may be missing something. Could someone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you test with 1.4.3 (which fixes many bugs from earlier point releases), or better yet, 2.0, and let us know if you still have the problem?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly in version 2.0. I guess we need to upgrade to the current version of eXist. Thanks!

Comment: Great.  Wouldn't have expected that bug in 1.4.1 - so unsure what might've been the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent two days fighting with it.
Adding "*" namespace to xPath solved the issue for me (my input file did not have any).

```
return <label>{fn:doc(fn:concat($collection, '/', $child))//*:testResult/text()}</label>
```